# Assign a command to my Tkinter buttons by looping over them

Tags: python, tkinter, button, calculator, factory

I would like to use a forloop to give my buttons a function in Tkinter. When I do it like this I get an error message, that those buttons are not defined. I tried several solution, but it did not work. I would be happy, if you could help me, as I am trying to make a calculator.

This is how the loop looks like:

```
for s in range(0, 10):
    def add_(s):
         entry_box.insert(1000, str(number))
```

And this is how i made a button:

```
button_zero = Button(main_window, text='0', padx=30, pady=25, command=add_0)
button_zero.place(x=67,y=430)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 10 buttons (0-9) that all insert a number into `entry_box`, I would make a function factory.

```
def add_(s):
    def wrapped():
        entry_box.insert(1000, s)
    return wrapped
```

When you call `add_(2)`, you get as a return a function that, when called, adds `2` to the entry box.

```
add_2 = add_("2")
add_2()  # adds 2 to the entry box, returns None
```

Then you can iterate through your buttons and assign a command to each.

```
for i, button in enumerate([button_zero, button_one, button_two, ...]):
    button.configure(command=add_(str(i)))
```

Comment: Why make a function factory when you can use the one already included in python: `functools.partial`.

Comment: @Novel personal preference mostly. `functools.partial` doesn't save me much programmer time, but does mean I have to remember to import `functools`! YMMV, it really doesn't affect the final code at all.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you provided your the command argument in button isn't equal to any defined function.  Maybe just a typo:

```
for s in range(0,10):
    def add_0(s):
        entry_box.insert(1000,str(number))
```